# What does ticking Core Date in project creation do?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3

it's been a while I'm working on a project and I just discovered that I have to use the Core Data framework. 
The issue is that I did'nt tick the Use Core Data case when I created the project and I don't know what I have to modify to make it work.

I think this is mostly in the AppDelegate but I'm not sure.

Thank you very much guys.

Elbattore

Comment: You can theoretically just create a new project without the tick, check it into some (local) git repo, delete all the files, create a new project at the same place with the tick and let git compare the resulting files. That will get you an *idea* of what the difference might be

Comment: it enables and set u default coredata for your project